# Registering DLL on windows mobile 6

Tags: c#, dll, compact-framework, activex, windows-mobile-6

I have a DLL file that contains an ActiveX control that I need to register it programmatically by code. here is the code I am using to register that DLL file but it keeps giving me "The system cannot find the file specified" when calling the Start method, And I do not know why regsvrce.exe is not found, should I change current directory or something, please help.

```
public static void registerDLL(string dllPath)
    {
        try
        {
            //'/s' : indicates regsvr32.exe to run silently.
            string fileinfo = "\"" + dllPath + "\"";

            Process reg = new Process();
            reg.StartInfo.FileName = "regsvrce.exe";
            reg.StartInfo.Arguments = fileinfo;
            reg.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            reg.Start();
            reg.WaitForExit();
            reg.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put a if file.exists in there. Suspect path or permissions, the latter being very likely as most of us get upset by foreign code doing this sort of thing without our agreement...

Answer (score 1):

Windows CE does not understand or support relative paths.  So first, you have to ensure `regsvrce.exe` exists on the platform (it's not a given that it will, in fact it's pretty common for it to *not* exist) and you must fully qualify the path to it:

```
reg.StartInfo.FileName = @"\Windows\regsvrce.exe";
```

If it doesn't exist (or even if it does) you could easily do the same thing `regsvrce.exe` does, which is to call `DllRegisterServer` by simply P/Invoking `LoadLibrary` and calling the method directly.